# Could not convert string to float using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

The error code I'm getting is;

```
line 83, in qu2
wins = float(wins)
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

This is the code that the error appears in

```
                wins = wins_box.get()
                draws = draws_box.get()
                loses = losses_box.get()
                wins = float(wins)
                draws = float(draws)
                loses = float(loses)
                total_score = 0
                total_score = total_score + wins * 3
                total_score = total_score + draws * 2
                total_score = total_score + loses

                yourvar = tkinter.StringVar()
                yourvar.set(total_score)
                totalscore1 = tkinter.Label(q3, textvariable=yourvar)
                totalscore1.pack()
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You should ``print()`` your ``wins`` variable - from the sounds of it, it contains a string that can not be converted to float.

Comment: I've tried and I'm trying to use the score as a window in tkinter, not pritned normally.

Comment: Most likely, you're trying to convert a blank string to a float. A simple way to debug this is to print the value before trying to convert it.

Comment: seems to still be the same

Comment: We can't help you unless we know what input you're putting into wins_box. As mentioned, likely a blank string, but we cannot know from your question.

Comment: did you `print(wins)` to see what you have in variable ?

Comment: the error occurs before i input any numbers or anythin

Comment: BTW: when you try to do `float(wins)` ? Directly after you create `wins` ? It will not work because program will not wait till you write something in entry. You have to convert (for example) in function assigned to Button.

Comment: So, How do I fix this please?

Comment: You can add Button with function which is executed when you click it (after you put text in Entry). And inside this function you can get text from Entry and convert.

Comment: do you know the command please, sorry im new to python and im doing a college assignment and the teacher is not that helpful lol.

Comment: effbot.org: [Button](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm)

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to convert the string "" into a float. "" doesn't make sense as a float, so you'll have to do one of the following.

1 Populate your fields with strings that make sense as floats. For example "0".

2 Set a default value. The following code sets wins as the float value of wins or 0.0 if not applicable.

```
try:
    wins = float(wins)
except:
    wins = 0.0
```

3 Specify "" to convert to 0.0:

```
if wins == "":
    wins = 0.0
else:
    wins = float(wins)
```

Comment: thank you, i will look in a moment, i am a bit busy at the minute.

Answer (score 0):

I think you use it in wrong place - directly after you create `Entry`. But `Entry()` is not `input()`, it will not wait till you put text, so every command after `Entry` is executed before you put text in entry. They are executed even before window is opened. `Entry()` only inform `tkinter` what element you want use in window. `mainloop()` will do all job (it opens window, puts widgets in window, gets key/mouse events, sends them to widgets, (re)draws widgets, etc., and back to getting events, etc.).

You can assign function with your code to `Button` and it will be executed after you click it (after you put code in `Entry`)

Example:

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def callback():
    text = e.get()
    try:
        value = float(text)
        l['text'] = 'square: ' + str(value**2)
    except Exception as ex:
        l['text'] = 'wrong float: ' + text

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

e = tk.Entry(root)
e.pack()

b = tk.Button(root, text='CALC SQUARE', command=callback)
b.pack()

l = tk.Label(root, text='here you will see result')
l.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: is there any way I can cap the number they can put for each one?

Comment: do you mean - filtering data allowed in Entry ? You can assing (`bind()`) function which will be executed after every key and it can check new text in entry and it can delete not allowed chars. See `<KeyReleased>` in code https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/tkinter/entry-bind-events/example-1.py